# Is it possible to backdate the timestamp found in a .gpg file?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

If I sign a file right now a check the `.gpg` file that's generated it will output a timestamp, is it possible to change the time when signing the file?

```
➜  Downloads gpg --verify cache.html.gpg 
gpg: Signature made Thu  9 Mar 14:27:07 2017 ACDT using RSA key ID A4DB4615
gpg: Good signature from "Tyler Bridger <xo@wvvw.me>" [ultimate]
gpg:                 aka "keybase.io/omgimalexis <omgimalexis@keybase.io>" [ultimate]
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's multiple ways you can do it:

- Change the system time, sign the file, then put the time back
- Run gpg inside [`datefudge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/datefudge.1.html) or [`faketime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/faketime.1.html)
- Use gpg's `--faked-system-time` option

Because of these possibilities, you can only trust the timestamp on a signature if you trust the signer to not have faked it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to prove that given data were existing before a given point in time by leveraging [OpenTimestamps](https://opentimestamps.org/) (source: [Gnupg-users mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2018-July/060810.html)).

> A timestamp proves that some data existed prior to some point in time.
> OpenTimestamps defines a set of operations for creating provable
> timestamps and later independently verifying them. At the time of
> writing timestamping on the Bitcoin blockchain is supported, the
> format is flexible enough to support a variety of methods.

Source: [opentimestamps.org/#how-it-works](https://opentimestamps.org/#how-it-works)

To sign leveraging OpenTimestamps:

```
gpg --clearsign doc.txt
ots stamp doc.txt.asc
```

To verify that `doc.txt.asc` existed before a given point in time use:

```
ots verify doc.txt.asc.ots
```

It is also possible to prove that some data were generated after a given point in time, as [this repository](https://github.com/opentimestamps/nist-inject) describes but I have not much investigated it.

Hence in theory it is possible to delimite a period of time when the data were generated.

Below is the technical idea behind OpenTimestamps to answer [Sir Muffington comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153352/is-it-possible-to-backdate-the-timestamp-found-in-a-gpg-file/274075#comment570768_274075):

The [More](https://petertodd.org/2016/opentimestamps-announcement) link foundable in [the link I provided](https://opentimestamps.org/#how-it-works) goes in the technical details. I have not quickly found a technical summary, so here is the main idea according to me: Bitcoin is a blockchain which is a decentralized block of transactions linked list, to add a block of transactions you have to partially inverse a hash function ([Proof of work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work)). While a fork, i.e. two branches not leading to consensus at the moment can emerge (for instance due to 2 blocks found and propagated at the same time), waiting a few blocks, 6 for instance, to have one branch exceeding the other by a few blocks make the other branch probabilistically discardable due to the cryptocurrency incentive. **As a result Bitcoin is a decentralized ledger not tamperable**, as it is a censorless append-only data structure. The idea of OpenTimestamps is to write in a transaction that is integrated to the Bitcoin blockchain a few minutes later (due to Bitcoin block frequency average being 10 minutes), a nonced hash of a document (signature in the context of this Stack Exchange question) that you want to timestamp. Once your transaction is in the blockchain it cannot be removed or censored, hence you can prove to anyone holding the Bitcoin blockchain that at a given Bitcoin block height the document you timestamped was existing. In the context of this Stack Exchange question, someone wanting to have a timestamp verifiable signature, can just follow this idea of putting it in the Bitcoin blockchain, then later on for verifying this timestamp, people can synchronize Bitcoin blockchain and receive from the signer the privacy nonce (avoiding to deduce what document was timestamped, as identical documents would have the same hash otherwise), then the verifier holding the privacy nonce and the original document can verify that the hash commited to Bitcoin blockchain match these two pieces of information. Now that you have a proof that your document was existing at some verifiable point in the past, then in the context of this Stack Exchange question the mentioned document is a GPG signature and you can verify it thanks to the signer public key valid at the associated block time. As a result you verified a GPG signature and that it was generated before a given point in time. Note that OpenTimestamps also uses Merkle trees to be able to commit a number of document hashes for a logarithmic price in their number, as to have a transaction integrated to the Bitcoin blockchain requires to pay a Bitcoin fee.

Some more details can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenTimestamps).

Comment: Welcome to the community. The how-it-works link appears to do not good enough of a job explaining how it prevents timestamp (which is just metadata!) tampering. Can you elaborate on this matter?

Comment: [I edited my answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/274075/revisions) to reflect technical details of OpenTimestamps.

Comment: Wait so you need to run a blockchain too just to secure your timestamps?

Comment: If by *need to run a blockchain* you mean for verifying securely the timestamps, then you do not have to synchronize [the whole blocks that are currently about 541 GB](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/charts/blocks-size), you just need to synchronize their headers containing the proof of work, it is 80 bytes per block, hence currently 825,764 * 80 = 66,061,120 bytes that is 66 MB. To be able to have independent from third-parties secure timestamps by downloading 66 MB seems fair enough to me.

Comment: By the way you only need to store the Merkle tree root for each block not being the last one, hence you only need to store about 825,763 * 32 = 26,424,416 bytes that is 26 MB. If [Bitcoin block headers](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/block_chain.html) were containing a [Merkle Mountain Range](https://github.com/opentimestamps/opentimestamps-server/blob/983aa187b852d5e36c92e67991f92775c5d2f338/doc/merkle-mountain-range.md) instead of a previous block hash, if you assume someone providing you a proof, like

Comment: [OpenTimestamps calendar server](https://github.com/opentimestamps/opentimestamps-server) or someone willing to prove you a timestamp, then you could only store the last block hash and Merkle tree root being 64 bytes, while a timestamp proof would have a logarithmic size in the given number of block transactions (as current OpenTimestamps proofs) and number of Bitcoin blocks. OpenTimestamps leverages the well established Bitcoin decentralized ledger for timestamping, Bitcoin serves many other purposes.

Comment: Ok if this works, this is brilliant. Could you also do a primitive PoC or just provide a link/picture/video of how someone did it? :-)

Comment: Isn't https://github.com/opentimestamps/opentimestamps-client and https://github.com/opentimestamps/opentimestamps-server already a PoC according to you? I am pretty busy these days so I cannot look for/provide you better explanations than what I did above. I just wanted to share something that I know both in theory and in practice work.

Comment: Oh the OP needs to run a server and a client? That ought to be mentioned. You already have my upvote btw ;-)

Comment: No, someone willing to timestamp a GPG signature does not need to run an OpenTimestamps server. The latter is only useful as a possibility to gather timestamp requests to exponentially reduce the associated cost, such that it is in practice free. If you are fine with having Bitcoin fees for timestamping, then you can only use a Bitcoin client, otherwise if you do not want to pay you can send your timestamp request to a server and hope it will take it into account, once taken into account by the server you can verify with a Bitcoin client. Note that any of both methods are as trustful.

Comment: I don't understand how you can prove a document was generated after a timestamp. That seems like proving it didn't exist before a timestamp, and I can't see a mechanism for that. The repos you linked to seem to still be doing "prove data existed before T". I know you said you didn't know much about it, but if someone who does can confirm / deny my assertion that would be helpful.

Comment: [The repository](https://github.com/opentimestamps/nist-inject) I linked describes it as such: *This is a simple script/bot that every 10 minutes grabs the latest NIST random beacon and a few blockhashes from various chains, concatenates them, and timestamps that file. This serves two purposes: 1. Timestamps the random beacons, proving they existed prior to a Bitcoin block. 2. Injects a commitment to the beacons into the Bitcoin chain, proving that Bitcoin blocks were created after the beacons.*

Comment: *In conjunction with the [Restamp](https://github.com/opentimestamps/restamp) Project, this provides evidence that can constrain when Bitcoin blocks were created both forwards and backwards in time.*

Comment: For instance you can prove to some extent that your signature was generated after a given point in time *T*, you can consider an event happening after *T* that you consider not predictable, for instance when electronically signing a document, you include in this document a The Time cover page published after *T*, that way assuming the signer could not predict The Time cover page, then its signature was generated after *T*. To enforce the security of this process you do not only consider The Time but all famous journals and then predicting all their cover pages is impossible.